# converting from bootstrap to materialize

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, materialize

Is it possible to convert a website that uses bootstrap to use materialize CSS? 
there is a lot of overlapping between those two frameworks, but I want to know if there is any feature in bootstrap that materialize misses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say materialize is more "finger friendly", as you get, out of the box, support for finger-actionable navdrawer, finger-dismissible snackbar, touch slider... (see images).

Bootstrap 3, as far as i know, does not have such support. Bootstrap 4-alpha is coming so maybe they add such ability.

Bad news is that materialize seems to lack, right now, the team that bootstrap has. It's freezed in v0.97 (personal opinion: feels like the team doesn't have the time to go on). Time will say if the project continues.

Also, there's a new competitor in town, google and Material Design Lite (http://www.getmdl.io/), but also, it still has not finger support (eg: see template http://www.getmdl.io/templates/dashboard/index.html)

[image: Toast] [image: NavDrawer]

Comment: What about button colors? If a project has had green btn-success buttons and red btn-danger buttons, etc. from Bootstrap, Material doesn't seem to have those concepts. I know I can use green and red wherever I want, but am I going against the grain of Material Design's intentions?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to convert a website that uses bootstrap to use materialize CSS?

Absolutely, though it will be a bit of work to update the class names and some of the markup structure.  Of course, it will take more work if your site is large and you've made a lot of customizations to Bootstrap, so it all depends.

> I want to know if there is any feature in bootstrap that materialize misses.

I think a better question to ask is whether Materialize has the features that you currently use, or think you might want in the future.  Of course you can't predict everything, but you can always add your own features later on if you find yourself missing something important.

As a sidenote, Bootstrap 4 is just around the corner, so you might want to tinker with Materialize for now while you wait to see what the next major version of Bootstrap has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

Materialize uses many bootstrap classes hence it is easier to convert it into materialize.
The best thing about materialize is that it provides a class for every thing,refer http://materializecss.com/helpers.html .
There are color classes, classes to align an element which we usually have to add styles.
It provides almost all inbuilt components that boostrap provides.
Following are the list of inbuilt components that we may have built via jquery and css in bootstrap.
1.Floating action buttons.
2.Feature Discovery.
3.Material Box
4.Parallax
5.Push Pin
6.Better Design for Nav /TAB
7. Toast Message.
8. Form components: chips, better UI for range.
The only difference is that , we need to initialize the components and also their documentation doesn't give enough understanding of customizing the components.

**Materialize has number of issues with its components like datepicker, select dropdown and many more components**